# Koa js : Err: Can't set headers after they're sent. mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await, koa, mlab

I'm using Koa 2's async functions.

I get the following error.

> events.js:163
>   1:56 PM
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>   1:56 PM
>         ^
>   1:56 PM
>   1:56 PM
>   Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>   1:56 PM
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:371:11)
>   1:56 PM
>       at Object.set (/app/node_modules/koa/lib/response.js:440:16)
>   1:56 PM
>       at Object.redirect (/app/node_modules/koa/lib/response.js:261:10)
>   1:56 PM
>       at Object.proto.(anonymous function) [as redirect] (/app/node_modules/delegates/index.js:40:31)
>   1:56 PM
>   Jump to
>   at url.findOne (/app/server.js:126:9)
>   1:56 PM
>       at model.Query. (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3737:16)
>   1:56 PM
>       at /app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:277:21
>   1:56 PM
>       at /app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
>   1:56 PM
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
>   1:56 PM
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
>   1:56 PM
>   6 minutes ago

This is part of my code.

```
async function red(ctx) {
  let redurl = "//url here";
  url.findOne({ shortenedLink: redurl }, (err, data) => {
    //find if short url matches long url in db
    if (err) throw err;
    if (data) {
      //if matches then redirect to long url
      ctx.redirect(data.url); //getting the error here
      console.log("matched");
    } else console.error("--"); 
  });
}
```

My full code can be found [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/ee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an `async` function, you should then follow the `async`/`await? pattern and not using callbacks. So you should rewrite your call like:

```
async function red(ctx) {
  let redurl = "//url here";
  try {
      data = await url.findOne({ shortenedLink: redurl })
      if (data) {
        ctx.redirect(data.url); //getting the error here
        console.log("matched");
      } else {
        console.error("--"); 
      }
  } catch (err) {
      throw err;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, as I used chained `sendStatus` function in my code as preceding.

```
Country.count({ name: name }, (error, count) => {
        if (count > 0) {
            console.log(count);
            error = name + alreadyExists;
            res.sendStatus(500).sendStatus(500);
        }
});
```

Removing the extra `sendStatus` fixed my issue.

```
Country.count({ name: name }, (error, count) => {
        if (count > 0) {
            console.log(count);
            error = name + alreadyExists;
            res.sendStatus(500);
        }
});
```